# problema de impressão com canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html5, asp

Tenho um form que imprime formulários de consulta, formulários criados usando canvas, e podem impressos n-vezes cópias, cada uma com uma numeração que incrementa no formulário.
Ocorre que em determinado momento, a definição do formulário se torna extremamente degradada, não sendo possível ler corretamente o formulário.
Como resolver isso?

[image: Imagem ruim para impressão - a partir de]

[image: Imagem boa para impressão - início]

Comment: Poderia colocar o código fonte que gera isso e talvez uma imagem com o problema/defeito.

Comment: Seguem as imagens, o código se dá em duas etapas, uma com um controle 'for' e outro com o arquivo de canvas propriamente dito (esse é bem extenso)

Comment: Pode ser que esteja redimensionando e o conteúdo seja uma imagem não vetorial e portanto isto cause perda de qualidade.

Comment: Bom, se estivesse redimensionando creio que o problema se daria logo na primeira folha (são várias folhas de um mesmo formulário), mas não foi o caso. De qualquer forma, o pessoal responsável pela criação do arquivo tinha feito uma versão em svg e me passou esta versão, cujo uso se mostrou extremamente eficiente. Agradeço a atenção dispensada :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sua aplicação talvez seja melhor utilizar o SVG ao invés do canvas, pois costuma ter uma renderização melhor.

Comment: Estou vendo com o pessoal que me enviou o arquivo com canvas para enviar um exemplo em svg, espero que resolva. Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Recebi os arquivos em svg e, depois das adaptações (inclusão de numero de formulário automático), estes se mostraram com melhor definição.